# Call decryption method from one activity to adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-adapter

I would like to ask how to call my decryption method from one activity to another(Adapter).

MessageActivity.java here is my decryption method:

```
  private String AESDecriptionMetod(String string) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] EncriptedByte = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    String decryptedString = string;

    byte[] decryption;

    try {
        decipher.init(cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        decryption = decipher.doFinal(EncriptedByte);
        decryptedString = new String(decryption);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return decryptedString;
}
```

MessageAdapter.java where I want to call decryption method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Chat chat = mChat.get(position);


    stringMessage = chat.getMessage().toString();
    stringMessage = stringMessage.substring(1, stringMessage.length()-1);

    String[] stringMessageArrey = stringMessage.split(", ");
    Arrays.sort(stringMessageArrey);
    String[] stringFinal = new String[stringMessageArrey.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<stringMessageArrey.length; i++){
        String[] stringKeyValue = stringMessageArrey[i].split("=", 2);
        try {
            stringFinal[i]= AESDecriptionMetod(stringKeyValue[1]);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringFinal.toString();


    }

    holder.show_message.setText(stringFinal);

    if (imageurl.equals("default")){
        holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
    }


}
```

And how to implement stringFinal in holder.show_message.setText(  ???  );

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: You can either copy the method in your Adapter and then call it, or you can make the `AESDecriptionMetod()` static and directly access it like `MessageActivity.AESDecriptionMetod(myString)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I move the method in Adapter and work.